# Check your wallet.dat passphrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, passphrase

Is there a way of using bitcoin core gui in order to check if you know/correct about your wallet.dat passphrase by typing it **only once**?

I know you can change the passphrase, but I want to keep it and not by typing it 3 times (The other two as the 'new' passphrase).

I'm aware it might be considered a bit of an odd question, but when security is so paramount, this could matter IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, open the command console inside the GUI and type
`walletpassphrase "your password" 1`

This will only succeed if the password is correct.

If you have multiple wallets, make sure you have selected the correct wallet at the top of the console.   The console only works on one wallet at a time.

Comment: Thanks @meshcollider.  Is there a way to do it (On windows) while the passphrase characters are hidden(Not shown on the screen)?

Comment: @mikest, if you have backed up your BIP39 seed to a BIP32 wallet on paper, then you can through your computer in a lake and won't have to worry about loss of funds

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the characters not to show on the screen, then instead of doing what @meshcollider wrote, you can begin a send process by inserting an address (Use one of yours, for safety).

Then write an amount that is BIGGER than whatever you have in the entire wallet (So it won't be sent no matter what), then try to send it. It will ask for your password.

If you give the right one, it will inform you that you can't send (You don't have sufficient amount), if you enter the wrong password, it will tell you that you inserted the wrong password.

Comment: It would be safer to use the "sign message" feature instead of send - sign message also requires an unlock.

Comment: Hi @meshcollider, I get errors about the addresses I generate and place there. It seems it require legacy addresses, which to my understanding are not generated by bitcoin core current version unless you mess with the config file.